# iPhone SDK4.0 and xcode 3.2.3 issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

My app was building and running well in xcode 3.2.2 with iPhone SDK 3.1.3. Now, I upgraded the SDK to 4.0 with xcode 3.2.3 and tried running the app. All I could see there after in the iPhone Simulator 4 is the opening splash screen (Default.png) followed by a BLANK BLACK screen. This is driving me nuts. No change in code yet, the app fails loaded in the latest xcode/simulator. Tried just about everything suggested in this past thread but no luck yet.

[Upgrade to iPhone 3.0 sdk and now simulator shows blank screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219330/upgrade-to-iphone-3-0-sdk-and-now-simulator-shows-blank-screen)

Btw, I have a MainWindow.xib in my project but I have extended the default UIWindow object.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue, found an answer in the thread that you posted that worked for me, not sure why it changed this value on my previously launched and active apps as well, but fixed the issue, resolved.

---

1. Open mainwindow in IB,
2. Select the "Window"
3. Under the inspector's "Window Attributes" (cmd + 1), make sure the [Window] property for: "Visible at launch" is selected!
4. Save (cmd + s) and then run!!

   ---

   Not sure how this got set to Unchecked, honestly I wasn't even aware that this was an option, guess some apps could make use of this, but I would imagine that most apps need to see the main window.

Hope this helps you out, was a life saver for me, I was going nuts trying to figure out the "Black Screen"

Comment: Thanks Newbyman. What worked for me was [window makeKeyAndVisible]. Some how I had missed/messed it up.