# Running Xcode project and getting a blank white screen!

Tags: xcode

I am new to iPhone development and I am getting a blank screen when I run a project that should show has few controls on the screen?
I am using iPhone simulator 4.1. Any help please?
Thanks
Sinan

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219330/upgrade-to-iphone-3-0-sdk-and-now-simulator-shows-blank-screen

Answer (score 0):

Did you used the sleep() function on the appdelegate.h file? if so try to remove it. worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you adding the controls to the right window?

I've answered [something like this before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232284/battling-with-xcode-not-displaying-my-uiwindow/6232960#6232960).