# Battling with Xcode not displaying my UIWindow

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, xib, uiwindow

***See edit at the end of the question***

I'm trying to get a simple iPhone app up and running and failing miserably :(

I have a very simple set up.  I have an app delegate, a view controller, and an xib file containing a `UIWindow` with a `UIImageView` and three `UIButton`s on it.  The problem is that when I start my app, the `UIWindow` never gets displayed.

I'm sure I'm just missing some sort of connection in Interface Builder (I'm running XCode 4, by the way).  I'm just completely lost as to what might be causing the problem.

I appreciate that this explanation is not great, so if anyone has any pertinent questions please feel free to ask them!

**Edit**: Ok, I can re-create my problem exactly.  If I create a "View based" application, then add a button (tried a slider too) to the created window,  when I compile and run, the button does not show up.  What gives?

Comment: You are actually asking 'What did I wrong?' without showing any code or explaining what you did. My answer is: You did something wrong.

Comment: @dasdorn: LOL.  With ya on that ;)  I was just hoping someone was gonna say ... have you forgotten to do "x"? ;)

Comment: If you just create a view-based project - does it run correctly out of the box? Before you change anything in the project?

Comment: @Abizem: Well it runs but all it displays is a grey screen (where I was expecting a white screen)

Comment: Meanies! I did re-qualify the question well enough to get a good answer in the end :P

Comment: A lot of those votes (including mine) came before your edit :)

Comment: @Abizem: I'm only kidding anyway :)  I'd probably have voted to close it myself :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you adding controls to the window nib or the view controller's nib?

Add your controls to the view controller nib.

Comment: To the windows's nib ... Is that my mistake?

Comment: To the window object anyway.  I can add a UIImageView to the view controller but no UIButtons ...

Comment: @Abizem:  So how do I add buttons to the View controller?

Comment: What are the names of your xib files

Comment: Ok I think I've got it.  The problem was that, by default, I didn't have a "View" object.  I created one and then dragged the controls on to that (While delegating it to the view controller) and now everything is working as expected!  Cheers for the help :)

Comment: No problem - Have fun! tbh - looking at your SO history I could see that was bound to be a simple problem to fix :)

Comment: O M G.  Even more stupidly I never even noticed that the view controller actually had a xib file.  My god I can be a retard.  I hate UI development.  Back end for the win! :D

Comment: @Abizem:  Thanks for the compliment :)  Yeah I can generally figure most things out but sometimes I can spend far too long battling with something that ought to be bleeding obvious.  This is a classic example ;)

Comment: Yeah - the naming is supposed to be helpful. By default, the view controller will load the nib named after itself. i.e `TestViewController` will load `testViewController.xib`. Here's a protip - override the controller's `initWithNibNamed:bundle:` to call `init` and then define `init` to load a nib that you've given a more useful name to.

Answer (score 0):

XCode default projects compile without you have to do anything. If you don't know where to start, and your app is actually simple, start again from the beginning, adding step by step a single functionality. This way it'll more useful for you and simpler for us :)

Comment: Yeah fair point.  I edited my original question with a simple re-production.